# The best way to copy data from one table to other ones

Tags: php, mysql, copy

I have one main table, and I need to copy the data from it to others. The whole idea is that the name of the tables that I have to copy into is dynamic (it is something like foo + one of the columns of the main table).

For example, if I have:

```
INSERT INTO maintable (id, addtoname, somedata) VALUES (1, 234, 'foo data');
```

I need to copy that data to: othertable234 ( somename + addtoname column )

I tried MYSQL TRIGGERS, but after some research I found out that it's not allowed to have dynamic table names.

The other thing that I have in mind, is to build up a PHP daemon script, to copy the data every 1-10 minutes. But I am concerned about the memory and performance issues.

So, what to you thing is the best solution to deal with this kind of problem?

Comment: What is the purpose of doing this?

Comment: The system I am working on is a GPS tracking system with more than 1000 stations. All the data from the GPS gadgets is inserted into the main table. So I decided that it will be faster to have separate table for each station ( for reading the data ). The thing is that I am doing the newer version of the system and I have to leave everything as it was working before, so people can still use the old on

Answer (score 1):

You can use any scripting language to do this, and use a scheduler (cron, windows scheduler) to run it every 10 minutes. The actual script only needs to issue a

```
create table tablename SELECT ...
```

So the only complexity is how the tablename will be derived.

Comment: And when the table already exists you can do INSERT INTO tablename SELECT ... FROM maintable WHERE ...